How to deal a data inside dict&list&string?
I got a json data that some value I need is hiding in a string, but Im not sure is there a good way to pick it out.
the data I need is an url inside the string but conclude list and dict like:
data_2 = content["a"]["b"][0]["value"]
print(type(data_2))
>>>> <class 'str'>
print(data_2)
>>>> [{"id":"123","name":"John","url":"https://www.data.com/"}]

and I have to pick up the value of url.
strip() doesnt help btw, Im still trying.
the thing is kinda like
{"content":{"custom1":[
{
    "value":"[{"id":"123","name":"John","url":"https://www.data.com/"}]"
}
]}}


What is expected output?

i wish to output the url's value, but the data_2 is a value from upper json data
kinda like "[{"id":"123","name":"John","url":"https://www.data.com/"}]" as a string.

Ah, I see. The problem is that you have a string formatted this way, not the actual list etc. You need to process it as JSON, since that's the format. Please see the linked duplicate. (But you should probably already know how this works, too, since you presumably did something similar in order to get content in the first place - right?)

For future questions, please copy and paste terminal output - don't try to re-type it. And please try to make exact examples - it doesn't matter if they're your real input (it's often better if it's not your real input), but it does matter that they can be used directly, without changes and are not just "kinda like" something.

Because you have shown data_2 to be String, the objects cannot be accessed directly. The json module can be used to first convert the String, then access first & only element of the list (a Dictionary( and then the url from the Dictionary.
import json

data_2 = '[{"id":"123","name":"John","url":"https://www.data.com/"}]'

data_3 = json.loads(data_2)

print(data_3[0]['url']) 

gives
https://www.data.com/
or you could accept the string and use a regex pattern to capture the required portion of the string:
import re

url = re.findall(r'\"url\".\"(.*)\"', data_2)[0]
print(url)

which again gives:
https://www.data.com/


Please don't answer obvious duplicate questions. Stack Overflow has existed for almost 16 years; surely you expected "how do I deal with this (JSON-formatted) string?" to be covered already?

im surprised ast and strip couldnt deal with it but json.loads can, thank you!
